# Does it matter in SQL whether conditions are grouped in case of a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sqlite

I do join 2 tables via SQL and add where clauses. The join is done by a condition in the where clause.
I wonder if it makes a difference whether the where clauses expect the join clause are grouped by brackets.

To ask with examples: is example 1 equivalent to example 2 and example 3?

Example 1 (no grouping):

```
SELECT * FROM employees, vacation 
WHERE employees.first_name = 'Maria' and vacation_start > 2017 
    AND employees.employee_id = vacation.employee_id
```

Example 2 (everything except join clause is grouped):

```
SELECT * FROM employees, vacation 
WHERE (employees.first_name = 'Maria' and vacation_start > 2017) 
    AND employees.employee_id = vacation.employee_id
```

Example 3 (join clause is first where argument):

```
SELECT * FROM employees, vacation 
WHERE employees.employee_id = vacation.employee_id 
    AND (employees.first_name = 'Maria' and vacation_start > 2017)
```

I always assumed that databases will optimize this kind of queries. 
But do they? I'm primarily working with MariaDB and SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are equivalent. But you should use explicit join instead of old `WHERE` syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
JOIN vacation 
  ON employees.employee_id = vacation.employee_id
WHERE employees.first_name = 'Maria' and vacation_start > 2017;
```

Simple logic:

```
-- AND has associative property
cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3
<=>
(cond1 AND cond2) AND cond3
<=>
cond1 AND (cond2 AND cond3)
```

Comment: I do indeed prefer the explicit join when I can, as it makes the table relations clear. However, the query is a result of a programming library where I cannot enforce the select-from-join variant :(

Comment: @capfan, the `JOIN` syntax is not a variant—it's standard syntax since 1992. There's no excuse for any programming library to not support it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The order of where condition will not matter but the order of tables you are writing in joins does matter.
2. If you keep the table with less records at left side of join will give better performance.
3. Regarding your WHERE condition, Optimizer will always push predicate down to make join operation faster. That means it will apply the conditions on tables first( employees.first_name = 'Maria' and vacation_start > 2017) and then perform join(employees.employee_id = vacation.employee_id) on filtered record set.

   If you check the explain plan for your query, you will understand it more.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping in **where** clause firstly matters only for logical expressions in your case. For instance;

> (A and B and C)

and

> A and (B and C)

are equivalent.

But

> (A or B and C)

and

> (A or B) and C

are different.

In your example all queries are the **same**. A little performance issues may occur with your grouping choices if you have very big data. If not no problem.